Supply only one IP address per each switch(cisco L3) port
I am small ISP and all my clients will be connected to each ports of Cisco N9K-C9372PX switch.
I need to disable L2 routing and supply only one IP per port(or maybe /30 subnet), actually how each ISP do.
Router Mikrotik CCR2116-12G-4S+
Nexus switches can't run DHCP server as I know

With a /30 you'll waste half your IP space. Why? And will port isolation do the trick for isolation? Regarding limiting number of IP's per port, that's likely to be difficult with the equipment you have. Possible perhaps by using DHCP relay on your nexus with vlan per port and static definitions in ISC DHCPd or similar, but sounds like a management nightmare.

This will be local ip, just to prevent client NAT over CGNAT. Port isolation is no good, this also stop L3 traffic. So I will probably leave big local network

it's impossible "to prevent L2 traffic and permit L3 traffic". These are layers, not different protocols; L3 (IP or IPv6) is always being encapsulated into L2 (ethernet, wifi) and travels either wires or fibers or radio, which are different kinds of L1 (physical) layer. You can't just have only higher layers without lower layers. Each (assembled) packet on the wire always has a L1 features (modulation, preambles, etc.), L2 header (MAC addresses and so on), L3 headers, and so on, up to application-level protocol data; all lower levels consider encapsulated higher layers as their payload.

What you can do is to implement something like Hetzner does: clients are assigned with /32 netmasks and given direct explicit routes towards the router, so all L3 is routed by the Hetzner, and no traffic is going directly between customers, so they able to use port isolation, but there's no IP address waste and there's an impression of a big shared IP subnet. If you want me to explain this idea deeper in the actual answer, tell here, I'll try.

I understand L3 will not work without L2. But who is Hetzner? OK, I can assign routes to each port, but how to assign proper IP to each customer? By MAC? It's bad idea. I will probably left it life this, I can use dhcp spoofing and broadcast spoofing. Something else?

What about port security mac-mac-count 1?

One can use proxy-arp or actually assign several IPs to a single machine, they'll will share MAC address so this port-security setting alone won't restrict to a single IP. Which is why it isn't called on the basis of "IP count". However, it's still a useful setting.
